# How to set a text with insertAdjacentHTM

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a table in html and I need help please with insert text using js

1. With putting a TEXT under the Price
2. At the moment I only managed to get my text under IMAGE but I would like help to put it under the PRICE.
3. Under $us21.00

```js
let text = document.querySelector(".product");
text.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", `<span>TEXT</span>`);
```

```html
<div class="order-summary__section__content">
  <table class="product-table">
    <thead class="product-table__header">
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">
          <span class="visually-hidden">Image</span>
        </th>
        <th scope="col">
          <span class="visually-hidden">Description</span>
        </th>
        <th scope="col"><span class="visually-hidden">Qt</span></th>
        <th scope="col"><span class="visually-hidden">Price</span></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-order-summary-section="line-items">
      <tr class="product">
        <td class="product__image">
          <div class="product-thumbnail">
            <div class="product-thumbnail__wrapper">
              <img class="product-thumbnail__image" src="//myimage.png" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
        <th class="product__description" scope="row">
          <span class="product__description__name order-summary__emphasis">Product1</span>
          <span class="product__description__variant order-summary__small-text"></span>
        </th>
        <td class="product__quantity">
          <span class="visually-hidden"> 1 </span>
        </td>
        <td class="product__price">
          <span class="order-summary__emphasis skeleton-while-loading">$us21,00</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: You can't put a span directly in a `<tbody>`, it has to be inside a `<tr>` and `<td>`

Comment: It's not clear what you want? Do you want to add another row to the table?

Comment: You need to add another `<tr>`. And to make the value go under the price, it will need empty `<td>` fields before that. You could use one `<td colspan="3">` to fill that space.

Comment: put the word TEXT under $us21.00 with my script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to insert a whole row, not just the span. Include `<td colspan="3"></td>` to fill the space in the first 3 columns of the table.

```js
let text = document.querySelector(".product");
text.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", `<tr><td colspan="3"></td><td><span>TEXT</span></td></tr>`);
```

```html
<div class="order-summary__section__content">
  <table class="product-table">
    <thead class="product-table__header">
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">
          <span class="visually-hidden">Image</span>
        </th>
        <th scope="col">
          <span class="visually-hidden">Description</span>
        </th>
        <th scope="col"><span class="visually-hidden">Qt</span></th>
        <th scope="col"><span class="visually-hidden">Price</span></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-order-summary-section="line-items">
      <tr class="product">
        <td class="product__image">
          <div class="product-thumbnail">
            <div class="product-thumbnail__wrapper">
              <img class="product-thumbnail__image" src="//myimage.png" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
        <th class="product__description" scope="row">
          <span class="product__description__name order-summary__emphasis">Product1</span>
          <span class="product__description__variant order-summary__small-text"></span>
        </th>
        <td class="product__quantity">
          <span class="visually-hidden"> 1 </span>
        </td>
        <td class="product__price">
          <span class="order-summary__emphasis skeleton-while-loading">$us21,00</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to append a new row inside the tbody and add a column with span of 4 (Since there are four columns each row) in order to take the entire row space.

Finally align the text to the right of the table

```js
let text = document.querySelector(".product");
text.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", `<tr><td align="right" colspan="4">TEXT</td></tr>`);
```

```html
<div class="order-summary__section__content">
  <table class="product-table">
    <thead class="product-table__header">
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">
          <span class="visually-hidden">Image</span>
        </th>
        <th scope="col">
          <span class="visually-hidden">Description</span>
        </th>
        <th scope="col"><span class="visually-hidden">Qt</span></th>
        <th scope="col"><span class="visually-hidden">Price</span></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-order-summary-section="line-items">
      <tr class="product">
        <td class="product__image">
          <div class="product-thumbnail">
            <div class="product-thumbnail__wrapper">
              <img class="product-thumbnail__image" src="//myimage.png" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
        <th class="product__description" scope="row">
          <span class="product__description__name order-summary__emphasis">Product1</span
              >
              <span
                class="product__description__variant order-summary__small-text"
              ></span>
        </th>
        <td class="product__quantity">
          <span class="visually-hidden"> 1 </span>
        </td>
        <td class="product__price">
          <span class="order-summary__emphasis skeleton-while-loading">$us21,00</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: And if the table had more rows and under each price I would like to put the text? how could i do

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting the table row. If you want to insert the text into the price cell, select the price cell instead

```js
let text = document.querySelector(".product__price");
text.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", `<div>TEXT</div>`);
```

```html
<div class="order-summary__section__content">
  <table class="product-table">
    <thead class="product-table__header">
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">
          <span class="visually-hidden">Image</span>
        </th>
        <th scope="col">
          <span class="visually-hidden">Description</span>
        </th>
        <th scope="col"><span class="visually-hidden">Qt</span></th>
        <th scope="col"><span class="visually-hidden">Price</span></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-order-summary-section="line-items">
      <tr class="product">
        <td class="product__image">
          <div class="product-thumbnail">
            <div class="product-thumbnail__wrapper">
              <img class="product-thumbnail__image" src="//myimage.png" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
        <th class="product__description" scope="row">
          <span class="product__description__name order-summary__emphasis">Product1</span>
          <span class="product__description__variant order-summary__small-text"></span>
        </th>
        <td class="product__quantity">
          <span class="visually-hidden"> 1 </span>
        </td>
        <td class="product__price">
          <span class="order-summary__emphasis skeleton-while-loading">$us21,00</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```